# Understanding $\rho^*\delta_0$ the pullback of the delta distribution by a function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory, pullback, fundamental-solution

I don't understand the meaning of theorem 6.15 (page 136) from the Hörmander Book "The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I".
It states a connection between the pullback of the delta distribution by a well behaved function:

> If $\rho$ is a real valued function in $\mathcal{C}^\infty(X),$ $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n,$ and if $|\rho'| = \left(\sum |\partial \rho / \partial x_j|^2\right)^{1/2} \neq 0$ when $\rho = 0,$ then $\rho^*\delta_0 = dS/|\rho'|$ where $dS$ is the surface measure on the surface $\{ x\in X \mid \rho(x) = 0 \}$.

The main problem I have is understanding the right part of the equation i.e.
$dS/|\rho'| .$
I have a general understanding of the surface measure but I have a really hard time understanding it in this context. Is there an example I can look up?

Comment: In an equation you have written $|p'|$. Should it be $|\rho'|$?

Comment: Have you tried some simple examples? Start with $X=\Bbb R^2$ and $\rho(x) = cx_2$ for different constants $c$.

Comment: That's a good idea @TedShifrin . $\rho (x) = 0$ if $ x_2 = 0$ and $|\rho'|$ is never 0. But I don't even know how to use the equation. Should I apply it to test functions $\phi$ ?
Is then $ \rho ^* \delta_0 (\phi) = \delta_0 ( \phi \cdot \rho)$
$ = \phi \cdot \rho (0) = \phi ( \rho (0)) $ ?

And this a surface measure? I'm totally lost in what that should tell me

Comment: sorry in the comment it should state $\circ$ instead of $\cdot$

Comment: It's going to a delta function concentrated on $x_2=0$. Surface measure in this case will just be (a multiple of) $dx_1$.

Comment: so it's
$$ \int_{-infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(x_1,0)}{|\rho'(x_1,0)|} dx_1 \ ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\Sigma:=\rho^{-1}(\{0\})=\{x\in X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \mid \rho(x)=0 \}$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional hypersurface if $\rho'\neq 0$ on it. The measure $dS$ is the [induced measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) on $\Sigma$; for $n=3$ it's just the area measure on a 2D-surface. The measure $dS/|\rho'|$ is defined so that $(dS/|\rho'|)(A)=\int_A (1/|\rho'|) \, dS,$ or equivalently
$\int f \, (dS/|\rho'|) = \int (f/|\rho'|) \, dS$ for every measurable function $f.$

Comment: Ok that makes sense to me. So the statement means that for any $f \in C_0^\infty(X)$ it holds that
$$f (\rho(0)) = \int_{A} \frac{f}{|\rho'|} dS$$
with $A = \{ x \in X \ | \ \rho (x) = 0 \}$ and $dS$ being of dimension the lebesgue measure of dimension $n-1$ ?

Comment: From where did you get $f(\rho(0))$?

Comment: I thought that was the definition of the delta Distribution $< \delta_0, \phi > = \phi(0)$

Comment: That is correct, but 
$$
\int_{A} \frac{f}{|\rho'|} dS
= \int_{A} f \frac{dS}{|\rho'|}
= \int_{A} f \, \rho^*\delta_0
= \int_{A} f(x) \, \delta_0(\rho(x))
\neq f(\int_{A} \delta_0(x)\,\rho(x)\,dx)
= f(\rho(0)).
$$

Comment: Ah I see. So $\rho^*\delta_0$ is a Distribution and it is something like this: (?)
$$ <\rho^*\delta_0, \phi> = <\delta_0 \circ \rho, \phi> = \int_X (\delta_0 \circ \rho) (x) \phi(x) dx \\
=  \int_X \phi(x) \rho^*\delta_0 = \text{ (by Thm) }  \int_A \phi(x) dS / |\rho'|
$$
Is that correct? Also what happens if $\rho^*\delta_0$ is not a regular distribution? Is there a way to phrase what $<\delta_0 \circ \rho, \phi>$ is then?

Comment: The pullback $\rho^*u$ of a distribution $u$ is defined by
$$
\langle \rho^*u, \phi \rangle
= \langle u, |\det d(\rho^{-1})| \phi\circ\rho^{-1} \rangle.
$$

Comment: Ok thanks! I think I got it now